# Embedded system: MSP430g2553 IAR programming ports/pins BASIC Input / Output syntax

Tags: c, io, embedded, iar

To put it simply : How do I define and use ports / pins correctly in IAR EW with MSP430g2553?

Ill use example to clarify what I do not understand.

I have a simple state machine with 3 states. I want to program 3 pins for input and 2 pins for output.
Then, depending on inputs I manage state.

First, is this correct way of defining inputs / outputs ?

```
 P1DIR |= BIT0 + BIT1; //pins 1.0 and 1.1 output
 P1DIR &= ~BIT2 + BIT3 + BIT4; // pins 1.2 , 1.3, 1.4 input
```

The above seems to me fairly straightforward to use, however, bigger question is how do I reference input pins in code ? And how do I set output based on input?

To further my problem, here is my starting code for this state machine and I've put in pseudocode where I dont understand how to write syntax. Would be of great help if anyone could fill in the pseudocode and commentate a bit. I've looked many tutorials but I dont seem to get this simple thing from them.

```
# include "msp430g2553.h"
# include "stdio.h"
# include "math.h"

#define START 1
#define LEFT_ON 2
#define RIGHT_ON 3

char STATE;

main ()
{

 P1DIR |= BIT0 + BIT1; //port 1.0 and 1.1 output
 P1DIR &= ~BIT2 + BIT3 + BIT4; // port 1.2 , 1.3, 1.4 input
 
 WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
 STATE =START;
 
 
 while(1)
 {
  //STATE = START;
   
   
   switch (STATE)
   {
   case START:
     {
     // Starting state I want both outputs to be set 1, I dont know how
       set p1.0 to 1
       set p1.1 to 1
       puts("START");

     //check inputs to switch state

      if (1.2 == 1 & 1.3==0 & 1.4==0) {
        STATE = RIGHT_ON;
      } else if (1.2 == 0 & 1.3==0 & 1.4==1)) {
        STATE = LEFT_ON;
      }  
     
     break;
     }
     
   case LEFT_ON:
     {
       // Here I wish to to put 1.0 output to 1 and 1.1 output to 0
          p1.0 set to 1
          p1.1 set to 0
       // now check if 1.3 is 1
          if (1.3 == 1) { 
             STATE = START;
             }     
       break;
     }
             
   case RIGHT_ON:
     {
      // Here I wish to to put 1.0 output to 0 and 1.1 output to 1
          p1.0 set to 0
          p1.1 set to 1
       // now check if 1.3 is 1
          if (1.3 == 1) { 
             STATE = START;
             }     
       break;
      }
   }//end of Switch  
 }// end of while
 
 
}// end of main
```

Comment: Let me give some clue, instead of P1DIR |= BIT0 + BIT1; , P1DIR | = ((BIT0) | (BIT1)); is better. secondly, in your state machine, there are so many int == double compression. Those comparisons will create UB for sure. Compare the same type values with each other.

Comment: "int == double compression. " what I mean here is pseudocode, I want to set pin1.0 to 1, this is pseudocode not actual. How to write syntax to create that pseudocode, thats what I wish to know.
If port1 pin 1.0 is output, how do i write syntax to change that pin to give output 1 ?

Comment: It's been too many years since I touched an MSP430, but similar to there being a P1DIR register for setting the direction of the pins on Port 1, there should be another register associated with the values of Port 1.  Maybe P1IN and P1OUT?  Also, you need to fix your P1DIR assignments.  Use bit-wise logic operators rather than arithmetic, and properly group things together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, is this correct way of defining inputs / outputs ?

I assume P1DIR is the correct data direction register (I don't know this particular MCU in detail), but apart from that: no, it isn't correct. First of all, use bitwise OR `|` not addition. They give the same result but `+` makes the code look strange and a bit harder to read. The average C programming book will tell you to do:

```
P1DIR |= BIT0 | BIT1;
```

Note that `P1DIR |= ...` will leave all pins currently set as output as they are. That may or may not be what you want.

To set a port pin active then simply do the same, `SOME_PORT_REGISTER |= PIN_MASK;`. Similarly, you can toggle a single pin with `^=` which is bitwise XOR. Or set it to zero with  `&= ~(mask)`.

`P1DIR &= ~BIT2 + BIT3 + BIT4;` is wrong, `~` is a unary operator that only applies to one operand. Corrected code:

```
P1DIR &= ~(BIT2 | BIT3 | BIT4);
```

---

> I've looked many tutorials

Most tutorials on the web are unfortunately quite bad. Start by reading a decent C programming book before anything else. Once you've learnt the basics of C, you can go look for tutorials.

For example this article about register access I wrote here, it assumed that the reader already knows C: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

As for full beginner tutorials, I think this one has better quality than most: [Embedded Software in C for an ARM Cortex M, Jonathan W. Valvano and Ramesh Yerraballi](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/embed/toc1.htm). (It's Cortex M not MSP430 but the principles are very similar no matter MCU. The same author also has an older tutorial that used NXP HSC12 examples, which is another 16 bitter even more similar to MSP430.)

Comment: Thank you! I will look into the resources you linked.
I think I also got it working as I kept digging and trying. I found I can directly set pins with binary / hexadecimal codes, ie. P1DIR |= 0x03 this sets pins 1 and 2 as output.
I can similarly set output ie P1OUT = 0x01 sets first output to 1 and second to zero.
And for input check I wrote a simple function that takes in mask char and input bits in char, returns result of & op.
My state machine seems to work well! This is for my school project, a line following robot. I get to test the code out tomorrow. I really like embedded systems